# Generating GitHub wiki pages from Doxygen style XML comments in c++

Tags: c++, xml, github, doxygen, wiki

I have Doxygen style XML comments for a c++ project I am working on, and would like to take it and make a GitHub wiki page from these comments. What would be the best way to do so? I cannot use GitHub pages. I have tried pandoc, but the pages it generates do not wind up looking nice, but I am not sure if that is because I am using it wrong or some other reason..

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: are you generating html files with doxygen?

Comment: Yes, but I don't believe html files can be used as wiki pages.

Comment: why can't you use Github pages? you can't have doxygen populate a `/wiki` if that's what you're thinking , those need to be built by hand (plus you should'nt be using a `github.com/user/repo/wiki` for that purpose anyways)

Comment: Pages are public. I was going to try to have the comments auto create the doxygen style documentation for the GitHub wiki so it can be looked at while on GitHub looking at the repo.

Comment: don't believe that's possible

Answer (score 0):

With [GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages), you can have either the `/docs/` or the root `/` of a selected branch to served `.html` files and it will be accessible through the regular `github.io` link: `https://<user_or_organization>.github.io/<repository>/` (it will be public regardless of your repo privacy), you can also have a GitHub Action to do so using the following template https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/static.yml.

And last part is to have an action that push (either on PR to your main branch or directly to main if there are changes to some directory), and that Workflow can be as simple as that:

```
jobs:
  build:
    name: ...
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # ...
      - name: Commit Doxygen updates
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git diff-index --quiet HEAD || git commit -am "Automated Doxygen updates"
          git push
```

There is no need to go through XML files, regarding the GitHub wiki comment, if you choose that over Pages, then XML files are the solution as you can convert them to Markdown files